# How to make Google Chrome's tabs behave more like Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Is there a way to have the following in Google Chrome, like Firefox?

1. A right arrow slider to navigate the tabs.
2. A drop down list of open tabs.

> [image: Wanted Result]

Answer (score 3):

The [TooManyTabs for Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp?hl=en) is what you are looking for, until Chrome improves its tabbed interface.

Comment: HOW have they not fixed their tab management 4 years later??

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is known as a "UI: tab overflow" bug and was reported Sep 2 2008.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=188

So almost 10 years passed since then... they had time to fix that, but just didn't want.

They could make it as an optional setting in preferences: "turn on/off tab scaling" or "make scrollable tabs" checkbox.

For me it was main reason why I didn't use Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do this yet but you can suggest them to do this on there [suggestion box](http://google-chrome.suggestionbox.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug it's by design as Google doesn't want to encourage the tab behavior you're talking about, so it's never something they'll implement as you're basically "using Chrome wrong" as far as they are concerned.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Google that addresses the problem. One of the existing answers claims there is a Chrome Extension for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a experimental feature that make chrome behaves like this.

You need to access the Chrome flags in `chrome://flags/` search for 'Tab Scrolling' and enable it.

[image: Example in image]